# Find dynamic content in div not iframe (python, selenium)

Tags: python, html, selenium, dynamic, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape dynamic content from a webpage. The page shows the 10 first elements and then I have to click a 'next' button to access the next 10 and so on. The button clicking works fine. However, afterwards, it returns only empty lists after the button is clicked.

I would like to get the content of the following element:

```
//*[@id="bt-collapse-442112-slider"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div/h3
```

I noticed that the first div has the attribute "data-currentslidecount" which is "10" in the beginning but is added 10 each time the button is clicked.

My initial code looked like this:

```
> for a in range(100):
>     WebDriverWait(driver, mywaits).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
> '//*[@id="bt-collapse-442112-slider"]/div[1]')))
>     print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bt-collapse-442112-slider"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div/h3').text)
>     WebDriverWait(driver, mywaits).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
> '//*[@id="bt-collapse-442112-slider"]/div[1]/button[2]')))
>     button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bt-collapse-442112-slider"]/div[1]/button[2]')
>     button.click()
>     button_count += 1
>     print(button_count) driver.close()
```

Trying to find a solution I found out that often, this problem occurs when content is embedded in iframes, and that one needs to switch frames to get dynamic content. However, in, my case, there seems to be no iframe.

Also, I tried using `find_element_by_css_selector` instead of by_xpath because I thought I could access the div like this or maybe even loop over the slide count. However, `

```
find_element_by_css_selector(div[data-currentslidecount="10")
```

produced a syntax error. I didn't find a solution online for this specific css selector and also, I am not very hopeful that this will be the solution to my problem.

**Edit:**

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="bt-slider row slick-initialized slick-slider" data-allitemcount="4184" data-currentslidecount="10"><button type="button" class="slick-prev slick-arrow slick-disabled" aria-disabled="true" style="display: block;"><span class="bab-slick-arrow-text">Zurück</span></button>
  <div class="slick-list draggable">
    <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 2264px; left: 0px;">
      <div class="bt-slide col-xs-12 bt-standard-content slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1132px;" tabindex="-1">
        <table class="table bt-table-data">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <p>Veröffentlichung</p>
              </th>
              <th>
                <p>Sitzung</p>
              </th>
              <th>
                <p>Beschreibung</p>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td data-th="04.02.2019">
                <p>
                  04.02.2019<br>Montag</p>
              </td>
              <td data-th="Sitzung">
                <p>19/78</p>
              </td>
              <td data-th="Beschreibung">
                <div class="bt-documents-description">
                  <h3>
                    78. Sitzung, 19. Wahlperiode, 01.02.2019</h3>
```

Comment: can you please share the html here?

Comment: thanks for the formatting improvements! I also added the html.

Comment: Try CSS like that and see any difference you get. `find_element_by_css_selector("div.slick-initialized")`

Comment: Yes, it works! Although I don't fully undestand why, I can now access the dynamix content appearing after clicking the button. Many, many thanks!