# Scrape pdfs links from dynamic content in div in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape some PDFs' links from the [Bundestag's website](https://www.bundestag.de/protokolle).
There is an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633910/find-dynamic-content-in-div-not-iframe-python-selenium) regarding the same very issue, but it does not provide an answer. However, I post it here for context and for further information in case they were needed.

My code works only partially since it only outputs and appends to the `pdf_links` only the link of the first PDF while it should scrape all the links from the page and then move (through `button`) to the next page.

My code looks like this:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Program Files/Chrome Driver/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.bundestag.de/protokolle')
button_count = 0
pdf_links = []  # Initialize empty list to store links
mywaits = 100
for a in range(10):
     WebDriverWait(driver, mywaits).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
    "div.slick-initialized")))
     elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.slick-initialized")
     for element in elements:
         pdf_link = element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a")
         pdf_links.append(pdf_link.get_attribute('href'))  # Append the href attribute to list
     WebDriverWait(driver, mywaits).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
    "div.slick-initialized")))
     button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.slick-initialized")
     button.click()
     print(pdf_links)
     button_count += 1
     time.sleep(1)  # Add a short delay to allow the new content to load
driver.close()

print(pdf_links)
```

And this is the output:

```
['https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf']
['https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf']
['https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf']...
```

For additional context, this is what the website looks like. In red, is the document the link of which gets appended to the list, and in green, is the button to pass to the next page of documents.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT**

*@Kunduk answer is not working correctly as it clicks the **wrong button** and returns only the first 10 records 58 times.*

This is the solution I have implemented to solve the issue. However. refer to @Kunduk answer for good practice. Although his answer does not solve the question, having to guess the exact iterations is not good practice. My answer may be useful as it implements a `By.XPATH` search in place of `By.CSS_SELECTOR`. Also, it allows retrieving more and older files.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Program Files/Chrome Driver/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.bundestag.de/protokolle')
button_count = 0
pdf_links = []  # Initialize empty list to store links
mywaits = 100
for a in range(445):
    WebDriverWait(driver, mywaits).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.slick-initialized")))
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a")
    for element in elements:
        try:
            pdf_link = element.get_attribute('href')
            pdf_links.append(pdf_link) 
        except:
            continue
    WebDriverWait(driver, mywaits).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.slick-next.slick-arrow")))
    button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.slick-next.slick-arrow")
    button.click()
    button_count += 1
    time.sleep(1) 

driver.close()
print(pdf_links)
```

Comment: Your `xpath` seems fragile, if any node changed this will start failing. Again random range not good practice, Tomorrow 100 more records can be added and your script won't be able to capture those records.

Comment: If this resolve your query, Please accept that as an answer and vote for it for future reader. Thanks!

Comment: It does not solve the issue because it doesn't scrape records older than January 25. I am trying to implement a hybrid answer with no much success ```except:
         
        try:
                nextButton=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.bt-paginierung__button--next:nth-of-type(2)")))
                nextButton.location_once_scrolled_into_view
                time.sleep(0.5)
                nextButton.click()
                time.sleep(2)
        except:
                print("No more next button!")
                break```

Answer (score 1):

Use `infinite` loop and check for the `next` button, if available, click on it and wait for page to load else break the loop.

Use `WebDriverWait()` to handle dynamic elements.

**Code**:

```
driver.get("https://www.bundestag.de/protokolle")
pdf_links = []
while True:

    for link in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.bt-documents-description>ul a.bt-link-dokument"))):
        pdf_links.append(link.get_attribute("href"))

    try:
      nextButton=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.bt-paginierung__button--next:nth-of-type(2)")))
      nextButton.location_once_scrolled_into_view
      time.sleep(0.5)
      nextButton.click()
      time.sleep(2)
    except:
         print("No more next button!")
         break

print("Total pdf links count : {}".format(len(pdf_links)))
print(pdf_links)
```

**Console Output:**

```
No more next button!
Total pdf links count : 580
['https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20090.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20089.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20088.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20087.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20085.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20084.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20083.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20082.pdf', 'https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20081.pdf']
```

[image]

Comment: The only issue is that there are many more than 580 PDFs that can be retrieved (see my solution). But I am not sure why your code would stop after 580 (to January 2023) while mine (if the iteration is set to 445) can reach back to files from October 2020.

Comment: You can see the attached. page number showing me as max `58` pages, 10 records per page  means 580 records.

Comment: Ah, I think I have figured: the code you have posted is clicking on the wrong right-arrow button (check the end of the page, there is an identical one that can be clicked only 58 times). I think that the site is a bit confusing, but the arrows are not the same it appears.

Comment: The answer is wrong: could you maybe update it? as you can see from your list of results, you end up scraping the same 10 pdf links.